# `rails server` hangs when there are multiple requests at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular

I have an angular2 app. I am using `resolve` to get some data before navigating to a `route`.

I was doing this in the route:

```
resolve: {
        businessRules: NewEventResolverService,
        countries: NewEventCountriesResolverService,
        locations: NewEventLocationsResolverService
}
```

Each of these services sends a GET request to my Rails API server (Rails 5).
So, when I was navigating to the said route, the rails server would hang and wasn't returning any data.

Then I changed it to only one resolver service:

```
resolve: {
        allPrerequisites: NewEventResolverService
}
```

And in the resolver service, sent the GET request one after the other.

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<any> {
    return this.service.getActiveBusinessRule().then((lookupRecords: LookupKeyValuePair[]) => {
        return this.service.getActiveCountries().then((countries: Country[]) => {
            return this.service.getActiveLocationsOfClient().then((locations: Location[]) => {
                return {
                        lookupRecords: lookupRecords,
                        countries: countries,
                        locations: locations
                }
            })
        })
    })
}
```

This time the server didn't hang. How do I make it work with multiple concurrent requests to the rails server?

Comment: Could you please elaborate *How do I make it work with multiple concurrent requests to the rails server?*

Comment: Make the first case work - all three requests sent to the server at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In Rails 5**

Make `config.allow_concurrency=true` in application.rb.